# JQuery mouse over question

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how can I delete the mouse over append when my mouse pointer is not over the element?

Here is the Jquery script.

```
$('.one').mouseover(function() {
  $('#log').append('<div>Handler for .mouseover() called.</div>');
});
```

Comment: Better would be to already of the element in your DOM and just show and hide it.

Comment: @Felix Kling what do you mean an example would be nice.

Comment: I mean that you already have the element in your HTML, example: `<div id="log"><div id="toShow" style="display:none">Handler for .mouseover() called.</div></div>`. It is initially hidden. Then you can use just `show()` and `hide()`: `$('.one').hover(function() {$('#toShow).show();}, function() {$('#toShow).hide();});` Maybe *better* was not the right term. It depends on the context. But it is definitely easier then appending and removing over and over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.one').hover(function() {
  $('#log').append('<div id="over">Handler for .mouseover() called.</div>');
}, function() {
  $('#over').remove();
});
```